# I want to link my Eastman Credit Union Checking account to my bitcoin wallet, pay the conversionr fee,to get my cripto being sent to my wallet

Tags: transaction-fees

I want to link my Eastman Credit Union Checking account to my bitcoin wallet, pay the conversionr fee 0f $76,so I can get my criptocururency funds transfered to from my Bitcoin Wallet. Then I can send funds to my checking account.